# Problem with running individual Nightwatchjs tests

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I've an issue where I can only seem to run individual ***nightwatchjs*** tests if I use the absolute path of the test script.

So, as an example, if I run my test from the following folder;

```
/Users/darrenharley/Documents/Git/uk-content-parkers/Tests/Functional/tests
```

with the following;

```
npm run test:live /Users/darrenharley/Documents/Git/uk-content-parkers/Tests/Functional/tests/current_functionality/gamAds/PAR-5139.js
```

It works correctly.

However, I need to run this test without using my local file structure (as will eventually be run via a Jenkins build so can't use this).

But if I run the test with the following;

```
npm run test:live ./current_functionality/gamAds/PAR-5139.js
```

it fails, with the following error;

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat
>   './current_functionality/gamAds/PAR-5139.js'

Am I doing something obviously wrong here?

If it helps, in my ***nightwatch.conf.js*** file I have this;

```
 src_folders: [
    'tests/',
  ],
```

and in my ***package.json*** file I have this;

```
"test:live": "nightwatch --config config/nightwatch.conf.js --env live --suiteRetries 3",
```

Any help would be appreciated, as this is driving mad as it seems such a basic thing to do.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, there isn't enough information regarding your Jenkins job to make a good educated guess (*Where is the NPM command being triggered from? What is the project root?*). So, your best bet would be to add a `pwd` prior to your NPM call & get a good understanding of what the project root is. Then, update your command accordingly.

---

**NOW ...**

For your task at hand, the easiest (*not to mention cleanest*) approach would be to leverage the NightwatchJS [test-groups](https://nightwatchjs.org/guide/running-tests/#test-groups) & [test-tags](https://nightwatchjs.org/guide/running-tests/#test-tags).

❒ Using [test-tags](https://nightwatchjs.org/guide/running-tests/#test-tags):

```
module.exports = {
  '@tags': ['PAR-5139', 'live', 'smoke'],
  'This is the PAR-5139 test': function (browser) {
     // > your code here <
  }
};
```

To enable the logic, your command will become:

`npm run test:live -- --tag PAR-5139` (*Please note the necessary prepending of `--` before adding extra NightwatchJS switches. It is needed to separate the params passed to npm command itself and params passed to your script.*)

❒ Using [test-groups](https://nightwatchjs.org/guide/running-tests/#test-groups):

Let's consider the following `tests` structure:

```
tests/
  ├── current_functionality
  |   └── PAR-5139.js
  ├── critical_functionality
  |   └── PAR-5140.js
  |   └── PAR-5141.js
  └── dated_functionality
      ├── OLD-90210.js
      └── OLD-NO7-BRAND-SOUR-MASH.js
```

To enable the logic, your command will become: `npm run test:live -- --group current_functionality`.

The `group` switch takes a list as a parameter, so you can chain multiple test folders in the same command: `npm run test:live -- --group current_functionality,critical_functionality`

**!Note:** Don't forget, you can also use the `--skipgroup` switch (*which can also be chained to exclude a series of test folders as well*). Also you can specifically disable a test case from the test run, using the `'disabled'` attribute to `true`:

```
module.exports = {
  '@disabled': true, // This will prevent the test module from running.
  'Not running this PAR': function (browser) {
    // > your code here <
  }
};
```

Comment: Great stuff, that's worked just how I wanted. Many thanks for your help @iamdanchiv

Answer (score 1):

The path being given is the issue. **The path needs to be with respect to the root**. In case of relative paths, they are picked with respect to root (where the package.json is located at top level).

If the directory structure is:

```
root
--tests
----PAR-5139.js
----
--src
--config
----nightwatch.config.json
--package.json
```

The command will be `npm run test:live ./tests/PAR-5139.js` irrespective to whether you run the command from inside tests folder or root folder.

In your case, the command is run from tests folder and path is also given with respect to tests folder but the command is looking for that file with respect to root and not the tests folder.

Hope it helps. Revert for any doubts.

Comment: Many thanks for the info @Sunil, I will be using this for some of my other tests.